# Generating classes at runtime / compile time with Dart

Tags: dart

A few questions about code generation with Dart:

1. Can dart generate a class at runtime with Dart for code running on the Dart VM?
2. Is there any sort of code generation equivalent to Java annotation processing at compile / pre run time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Dart VM and dart2js don't support generating code at runtime.
One workaround is to generate code to a file and load it in a new isolate (can also be a data URI). The application can communicate with the generated code running in another isolate only by message passing.

2) This is what [transformers](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/transformers/) are for, but transformers are only applied to dart2js (or pub serve at development time), but not to code run on the server side Dart VM.

https://github.com/dart-lang/build (currently only in developer preview) can be used for code generation for browser and server-side code. It's a tool that monitors source files and updates generated code when source file change.

Comment: I see. I had thought of the first approach. Do you have any insight to the overhead of an isolate and message communication? I couldn't find much information on the isolate performance that was up-to-date

Comment: I'd assume that it's much slower than passing values within the same isolate, but it's still just in-memory, therefore much faster than a network request. You'd need to do some benchmarks for your specific use case to get proper results. I think it also depends a lot on the kinds of values you send (primitive values, maps or lists, or custom class instances or trees of custom class instances.

Answer (score 0):

I've now discovered that the dart team has a library for generating sources. It seems useful for generating sources pre-compile time: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/source_gen